# Unable to start debugging my C++ program under VS Code: "Unknown Error: 0x803d0014"

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++17, vscode-debugger, windows-11

I've been developing/debugging using VS Code and community edition of MSVC 2022. All was working fine.

today during one of my sessions, when I tried to start the debugger I got:

> Unable to start debugging. Unable to start program '<my program's name>'. Unknown Error: 0x803d0014

The program start without problem from the command line, it is really the debugger that stopped launching as far as I can tell! right in the middle of an endless loop of: edit, compile, debug. My target architecture is amd64 commonly known as x64.

Here is my code I want to debug:

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << std::format("arg[{}] -> {}", i, argv[i]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my launch.json file for debugging:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "simple_example2",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/Users/wonix/dev/build/csvGenerate/Debug/csvGen.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the result of compiling:

```
[main] Building folder: dev 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build c:/Users/wonix/dev/build --config Debug --target csvGen -j 10 --
[build] Version MSBuild 17.7.2+d6990bcfa pour .NET Framework
[build] 
[build]   Checking Build System
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/Users/wonix/dev/csvGenerate/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   main.cpp
[build]   csvGen.vcxproj -> C:\Users\wonix\dev\build\csvGenerate\Debug\csvGen.exe
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:05.755
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
```

Compile fine, run fine, just cannot debug it.

I close VS Code and restarted it, still same problem!
I rebooted my machine still same problem!

Comment: we need a [mre] (that includes how exactly you built your executable). see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4707 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/316

Comment: I added some code, doest the question needs to have more info provided ?

Comment: This issue looks a lot like mine, but sadly not solution yet!
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10596

Comment: are you also on a Windows for ARM machine?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an instance of the problem raised in this issue ticket: [Unable to start debugging, since 1.14.3 (Windows 11 ARM) #10596](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10596). Here's what you can do: If your system info is not already listed there (C/C++ extension version, OS version, host and built-target processor architecture, etc.), you can comment with what your system info is to help the maintainers know how else to reproduce the issue. Give the issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it getting addressed and to increase its prioritization. Subscribe to the issue ticket to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like ones just containing "+1" / "bump".